# Cakephp error: Authentication adapter "xmlRpc" was not found

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

x gives me an error "Authentication adapter "xmlRpc" was not found" when I try implement a custom login component.

In my AppController.php I have the following

```
<?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

//Custom Auth
App::uses('xmlRpc', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class AppController extends Controller {

    //Authentication component

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                    'xmlRpc'
                )           
            )
        );

}
```

Then I have my login compononent located in /Controller/Component/Auth/xmlRpc.php

```
<?php

App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class xmlRpc extends BaseAuthenticate {

    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

In my users controller I have the following:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

//Custom Auth
App::uses('xmlRpc', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function logout() {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }   

    public function login() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if ($this->Auth->login()) {

                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                // Prior to 2.3 use `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());`

            } else {

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
            }
        }
    }

}
?>
```

By the way in my authenticate function I always return true just for testing. Will add logic once I get rid of this error. Please assist and take it easy on me because im a Cake n00b. How to I get cake to see my custom authentication adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the CakePHP naming conventions, the class should be named `XmlRpcAuthenticate`, the file too (with `.php` extension of course). In the `App::uses()` call and in the configuration use the name without `Authenticate`, ie `XmlRpc`.

```
// This App::uses()  call is actually not necessary in the controller unless
// your are actually trying to access the class directly
App::uses('XmlRpc', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

...

public $components = array(
    ...

    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
             'XmlRpc'
        )           
    )
);
```

See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects

Answer (score 0):

I think the right name for your Authentication adapter should be xmlRpcAuthenticate

```
class xmlRpcAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate {
```

Answer (score 0):

just make first letter capital of your function, i also solved it this way.. Thanks